# getting this error { a function body must be provided error }

Tags: flutter, dart

There is an error in the override:
[image: function body error]

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Row(
          children: [
            Text("Flutter"),
            Text(
              "News",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )
          ],
          

        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final image, categoryName;
  CategoryTile({super.key, this.categoryName, this.image})


  // ignore: empty_constructor_bodies
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack( children: [
        Image.asset(image,
        width: 120,
        height: 60,
        )
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

A function body must be provided error.
I don't know how to solve this & so I can get some help.

Comment: add a line end(`;`)   like `CategoryTile({super.key, this.categoryName, this.image});`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` after your constructor :

```dart
class CategoryTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final image, categoryName;
  CategoryTile({super.key, this.categoryName, this.image});


  // ignore: empty_constructor_bodies
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack( children: [
        Image.asset(image,
        width: 120,
        height: 60,
        )
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

It should be better like this

Answer (score 0):

When you define a constructor, you need to provide a function body for it.

Here is the updated code:

```
class CategoryTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final String categoryName;

  CategoryTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.categoryName,
    required this.image,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            image,
            width: 120,
            height: 60,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```